# Debug an IOS app on Windows PC

Tags: ios, iphone, phonegap, weinre

I have developed a mobile app for IOS, Andriod and Windows devices. The application was developed with Phonegap.

I am running into a few issues while testing. Everything works perfect on Android, Windows and iPad, however once the app is on an iPhone 7 with operating system 11.2.5 there are a few "quirks". For instance select menus are self selecting and causing the app to crash. This only happens on the iPhone.

I am trying to debug this using weinre to debug, and I am unable to successfully get the iPhone to connect.

Is there options to see a console log, web inspector to find these errors?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don’t you need a Mac to deploy? What’s the point in building a Mac app if you can’t actually deploy it.

Comment: I have been using MacinCloud to deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap serve and weinre. 
Running both. I was able to pin point the issue..

Needed to update plugins.